# Universal Analytics clientID

Tags: universal-analytics

Recently we upgraded to universal analytics which appears to all be working. I have been trying to capture the clientID to a js variable via the following code:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-REMOVED', 'xxxx.xxx');
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga(function(tracker) {
var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
</script>
```

To prove the variable clientID is being captured I try and write it to the page using the following code:

```
<script>
document.write(clientId);
</script>
```

Which writes nothing to the page.

I have browsed this site and others but can not figure what i am missing. I feel like i'm overlooking something blindingly obvious. Any help much appreciated.

Ultimately i will be writing the variable to a form field to process offline steps occuring in a 3rd party system.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the variable clientId is declared inside a function. Hence, 'clientId' does not have a global scope. Its value is not accessible outside of the function. Need to assign the value from `tracker.get('clientId')` to a global variable if you need to use it later. See `http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/`

Answer (score 0):

Calling the following does work on my page:
    ga(function(tracker) { alert(tracker.get('clientId'));})

I am doing exactly the same thing as you but instead of writing it to a page, I am alerting it. Maybe `document.write` is not working for you as expected?

If the code you posted is same as the one you are using, The reason it is not working is because `document.write` runs before the callback is called. remember that everything that you pass into `ga()` is asynchronous.

Comment: actually is the same as the issue reporte,  ga(function(tracker) { alert(tracker.get('clientId'));}) uses clientId in the local scope of the function that looks it up.